# How to receive only data in I2C master of stm32?

Tags: stm32, i2c

Now I have two stm32 chips, two stm32's I2C connect to the same device, one stm32 is used to send data to the device and also receive data; the other stm32 only receives the data returned by the device, how should I set up the I2C for this stm32?

I don't know how to set another I2C parameter that only receives data.

Comment: You can't use the standard I2C communication to achieve that as I2C master only communicate with the designated I2C slave by addressing the slave with the I2C address. Your second MCU is neither a Master nor a Slave. You need an [I2C sniffer](https://github.com/kongr45gpen/i2c-sniffer) which uses two GPIO pins and interrupt to intercept the data on the I2C bus.

Answer (score 1):

Only I2C master can initiate communication. When I2C master wants to read something from the slave, the master sends it a data request.

Some I2C slave devices can have a special interrupt pin, which can signal the master (through GPIO rising/falling edge interrupt) that they have something to be read from them, but it's not a part of I2C (and it doesn't look like you have anything of this sort here).

My proposal for you is:
Use exactly the same I2C configuration on both, just don't use "send" functions on the second MCU.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the standard I2C communication to achieve that as I2C master only communicate with the designated I2C slave by addressing the slave with the I2C address. Your second MCU is neither a Master nor a Slave. You need an [I2C sniffer](https://github.com/kongr45gpen/i2c-sniffer) which uses two GPIO pins and interrupt to intercept the data on the I2C bus.